# Jquery / PHP insert value in input based on a joined [input value & column name]. jquery 1.9.1 or php

Tags: php, jquery

I have the below table:

```
<table class="authors-list" border=0 id="ordertable">
  <tr>
     <td ><input type="text" id="product_1" name="product_1" class="rounded"/></td>
     <td ><input type="text" size='5' id="qty_1" name="qty_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h09_1" name="h09_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_09" name="line_1_09" value=""></td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h12_1" name="h12_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_12" name="line_1_12" value=""></td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h15_1" name="h15_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_15" name="line_1_15" value=""></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="cubespercheck_1" id="cubespercheck_1" value="0" size=5></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Befc/7/

My main goal is to be able to post each checkbox as an individual product. the product field is populated with a product family. example is 38114CR. the checkboxes represent the lengths of the product. the code for a 1.8 meter length of 38114CR is 3811418CR where 18 is the length (1.8)

In the end, I want to be able to post each checked checkbox as its unique product code. so if 0.9 is checked for product 38114CR post the value 3811409CR.

My ultimate goal is to insert the following into a database:
(this is as per the fiddles desired result)

```
**Product           Cubes**

3011409CR           7
3011412CR           7
2011512EX           3
2011515EX           3
5050009PT           2
5050012PT           2
5050015PT           2
```

The only way I can think of is to loop through the table, and where there is a checked checkbox, combine the name and the length but even that has some challenges.

How can I get the above table rows to insert into a database? so horizontal row to vertical record insert?

Keep in mind that the user can input any product code they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#continue').on('click', function () {
        createcodes();
    });
});


function createcodes() {

    //run through each row
    $('.authors-list tr').each(function (i, row) {

        // reference all the stuff you need first
        var $row = $(row),
            $line = $row.find('input[name^=line]'),
            $family = $row.find('input[name*="family"]'),
            $size = $row.find('input[name^=size]'),
            $grade = $row.find('input[name*="grade"]');

        $line.val(
            $family.val() + ' ' + $size.val() + ', ' + $grade.val()
        );

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden fields. On each row add a hidden field, witch will contain the "real value".

Then add a click/change/whatever event you want to the checkbox, and if user can type the codes a keyup to the input field. The event should send the ending of the "lines" of the ids (like _2, _2, etc. -> in the way you named them).

All events should call the same function, witch will concat the values into the hidden field.

Something like this - is an example copy paste won't work ;) :

```
     function makeName(line) {
         // Loop through checkboxes on that line and make the name
         if (<checkbox is checked>)
              document.getElementById('hiddenField' + line).value = document.getElementById('product' + line).value + <checkboxFromLoop> // Etc., etc.
     }
```

On submit just send only the hidden fields. They will contain the correct values.

Comment: Thanks Zozo. this makes sense. problem is that an earlier jquery script checks or unchecks the checkboxes based on some logic from database. how can I get this to fire and loop through each table row and cell to perform this? there will not necessarily be a click on the checkbox? Thanks again.

Comment: You can modify the script to trigger one more event (the easiest way in my opinion, I don't exactly know what you have there so I might be wrong), or you can try an "onchange" event for checkboxes. I don't guarantee about the onchange but it might work. I will try it myself later but can't right now :)

Comment: Thanks Zozo, any chance of a more accurate script? getting myself crazy with this one. Thanks.

Comment: you can see http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/2/ for fiddle. I have created and populated the hidden fields(still visible) just need to join each of them using the jquery loop for checked checkboxes. Thanks.

Comment: Can't promise a more accurate script today... things are a bit crazy here (at work) right now. I'll try to edit it into something more useful tonight if I'm not to... dead. +1 for fiddle :).